# Anyone using Otter for Configuration Management?

Tags: windows, continuous-deployment, devops, configuration-management, orchestration

I am exploring various tools for automating our windows infrastructure like Puppet/Chef/Ansible etc. Recently I came across Otter (http://inedo.com/otter). This is relatively a new tool in the market so wanted to know if anyone has already used it and if yes would appreciate if they can share their experience.

Answer (score 0):

We tried it for a while but dropped it again, we simply hit to many issues.

However, the product does seem promising and their support/dev team are quick at solving issues.

I would recommend trying it, as there are very few Windows "first" configuration management tools.